# INNER JOIN one table, to many rows of the other table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables

```
// foo
owner_id varchar(255)
// bar
foo_id varchar(255)
```

I want to make a query that gets all `foos`, that have a `bar`, and attach the bars onto each foo.

```
[
  {foo, bars: [.....]},
  {foo, bars : [....]},
]
```

I am trying to use an inner join -->

```
SELECT *
FROM
  foo
INNER JOIN
  bar ON foo.id = bar.foo_id
WHERE 
  foo.owner_id = ?
```

but this creates the result ->

```
[{fooA, ...merged bar}, {fooA, ...merged bar}, {fooB, ...merged bar}]
```

Comment: If you want one row "per foo", you'll need to `GROUP BY` "the foo" and use one or more aggregate functions to merge the associated "bar" data; such as `GROUP_CONCAT()`. You cannot get each bar as additional columns, as that would likely result in result rows with varying columns.

Comment: SQL doesn't have arrays, so it's not clear what you mean by that result. If you're processing the results in a programming language like PHP, you can combine all the rows with the same `foo` into a single object.

Comment: If you're using PDO, you can use `PDO::FETCH_GROUP` to make it create the grouped array automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT foo_id,group_concat(bar_id/bar_name)
FROM
    foo
INNER JOIN
    bar ON foo.id = bar.foo_id
WHERE 
    foo.owner_id = ?
    group by foo_id;
```

This will give you all bars for given foo.